# Use RestKit with file-based URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, restkit

I want to use RestKit with a file-based URL:

```
file://localhost/Users/me/somefile.json
```

However, when I start a request with RestKit, RestKit can't create the corresponding `RKURL` object although the original is a valid `NSURL` object (`completeURL` is nil):

```
NSURL *completeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:completePathWithQuery relativeToURL:theBaseURL];
if (!completeURL) {
    RKLogError(@"Failed to build RKURL by appending resourcePath and query parameters '%@' to baseURL '%@'", theResourcePath, theBaseURL);
    [self release];
    return nil;
}
```

Are file-based urls generally supported by RestKit?

**Update**: I posted [an issue](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/942) at RestKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just quoting the answer in the question owner's Update [link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/942) so people may find it easier.

> I found the problem I was having. It looks like I can't use `@"file://localhost/Users/me/Folder"` as baseURL, but rather `@"file://localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

That is a NSURL method you are calling that is failing. Filing an issue with RestKit will not get that fixed.

From the documenation:

> **Return Value**
>
> An NSURL object initialized with URLString and baseURL. If URLString was malformed, returns nil.

Comment: I am not calling this method. This is [inside RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Code/Network/RKURL.m#L87). So RKURL does some additional logic which seems to fail for file-based URLs

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, but RKURL supports file-based URLs (look at how they handle database seeding for example)